# WSO2 Share same user between two tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a user in tenant1 and i want the same user with same password in tenant2 also. How to achieve this in WSO2.

I did some workaround by creating same username and password in multiple tenants but this would break if any one of the tenant's password changed

Basically how to share same user between multiple tenants in WSO2 Identity Server? I am using wso2is 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same userstore for both tenants as secondary userstores.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores